# I got ReferenceError: Firebase is not defined during push the data into Firebase DB in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

How to fix this error ?

```js
//Here this is our controller code
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["firebase"]);
 app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $firebase, $firebaseObject) {

 $scope.submitData = function() {
  var name = $scope.user;
  var pass = $scope.password;
  var firebaseObj = new Firebase("https://angulardemo-72e92.firebaseio.com/");
            var fb = $firebase(firebaseObj);

        fb.$push({ Name: name,Password: pass}).then(function(ref) {
            console.log(ref);
        }, function(error) {
            console.log("Error:", error);
        });
 } 

});
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="firebase.js"></script>
  <script src="angularfire.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script>
   // Initialize Firebase
   var config = {
     apiKey: "AIzaSyBQksCCUXGkotmwBDSPUBfQvIC-xt9p5DY",
     authDomain: "angulardemo-72e92.firebaseapp.com",
     databaseURL: "https://angulardemo-72e92.firebaseio.com",
     projectId: "angulardemo-72e92",
     storageBucket: "angulardemo-72e92.appspot.com",
     messagingSenderId: "230268694130"
   };
   firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>
 <body>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
   Enter Name<input type="text" ng-model="user"><br>
   Enter Passwrod <input type="text" ng-model="password">
   <button type="sumbit" name="sumbit" value="sumbit" ng-click="submitData()">LOGIN</button> 
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Hello sir, I have to push the data into the firebase DB but I got an error firebase is undefined, in AngularJS please tell me whats the wrong in my code ?

Comment: Remove the code between your script tag because firebase is undefined there. Check https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/using-firebase-with-angularjs--cms-22233 for more details on how to use firebase with angular

Comment: Means sir.. i have to remove the  -  // Initialize Firebase code from script?